# SQL syntax question

Tags: sql, oracle

What do the following mean in an sql sytax:

1. (+) after a condition 
   eg: "WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col2 (+)
2. What does /* */ after select signify , i vaguely remember it being a suggestion to the optimizer, but where can i find more reference on this
   eg: select /* */ ...

Comment: Sorry about all the edits it seems 2 of us tried to edit at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The `(+)` means an outer join syntax for SQL on Oracle.
2. The `/*` alter the SELECT means a comment. In Oracle if the comments starts with `/*+` (A plus after the comment token, means a hint, for instance `/*+ORDERED*/`

Comment: ah yes, those are hints. I can google for further reference. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking oracle then the `(+)` is an outer join and `/* some stuff */` is a comment. If the comment is of the form `/*+ hint* */` then the comment is probably a hint. [google on oracle hints](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENUK243&q=oracle+hint&meta=lr%3D)

Comment: I tried editing to add the inline-code backticks.  Does that make it do what you want?

Comment: Close, was trtying to get the rem hint in italics /*+ hint */

Answer (score 2):

By the way, a lot of business intelligence is stealth in SQL queries - and most queries, as long as they can be, do not have comments at all !

This is a shame :o)

Adding /* */ comments in a query should be done every time the query is not obvious. That is to say, most of the time...

A+
Sylvain.